# IConfiguration - how to bind dynamic values from configuration to object

Tags: c#, .net

I am having configuration.ini file which contain following content ->

```
[Objects]
obj1={7CE7ECE0-B70D-4622-8F4B-D999E5F06AAD}
obj2={5964945B-C31B-4805-9408-D56A4A5457CF}
obj3={5964945B-C31B-4805-9408-D56A4A5457CF}
```

Those keys - objN can be dynamically added.

With help of ConfigurationBuilder I am creating the config ->

```cs
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .AddIniFile(Path.Combine(configFolderPath, @"Configuration.ini"))
     .Build();
```

Now when it come to the topic of Binding to object I get stuck and cant find any solution.

```cs
services.AddOptions<SomeObject>()
                .Bind(_configuration.GetSection("Object"))
```

P.S

As temporary solution I found is to get configuration section as enumerable which is `dictionary<string,string>` and then map it manually. This is just look quite dirty.

```
configuration.GetSection("Objects").AsEnumerable()
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `configuration.GetSection("Objects").Get<Dictionary<string, Guid>()`?

Comment: Not really. Honestly speaking map to something is not the problem. Map to Object and make it registered to DI that's what would be nice as I am doing something like `_services.AddOptions<SomeObject>().Bind(_configuration.GetSection("Objects"))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would say **Guru Stron** gave you the answer.

```cs
services.Configure<Dictionary<string, Guid>>(_configuration.GetSection("Objects"));
```

Then, consume with DI:

```cs
public class SomeService
{
    private Dictionary<string, Guid> Objects { get; }
    public SomeService(IOptions<Dictionary<string,Guid>> objects)
    {
        Objects = objects.Value;
    }
}
```

If you feel that `Dictionary<string,Guid>` is not a specific-enough data type, simply create a derived class:

```cs
public class MyObjectDictionary : Dictionary<string, Guid>
{ }
```

Then use `MyObjectDictionary` as the type in the call to `services.Configure<>()`.

Comment: Thanks going to try it tmr and come back :)

Comment: seems works as charm) Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be working for you

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _objects ;
        public MyClass(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _objects=config.GetSection("Objects").Get<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            Console.WriteLine(_objects["obj1"]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using the INI configuration provider for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#ini-configuration-provider

As for dynamic loading, You can use IOptionsSnapshot or IOptionsMonitor.